# Why the "Server not found" error when I enter the address - http://localhost:8080/ on my browser

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine. I am able to start the appserver from the command prompt of Windows and its showing "Info : The server is running at http://localhost:8080/" but still when I enter the address on my browser its showing the Sever not found error.

Comment: I'd check if it's a firewall issue. I have windows 7 and I can run the server and view it at localhost:8080

Comment: I have disabled the anti virus application, but still the error persists

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your app.yaml file as well as the handler definition for '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a quite a few reasons this could be happening. If you have checked your firewall settings I'm willing to bet that there is an issue with your app.yaml file.

If your main python script is called main and is located in the root directory of your application code a working example of an app.yaml file is:

```
application: yourapplicationname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Also make sure that within your main.py file the routes are correct.
eg:

```
  from google.appengine.ext import webapp

  class Main(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.out.write('Hello World')

  def main():
      application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Main)],
           debug=True)
      util.run_wsgi_app(application)


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```